# Ember.js not sideloading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the need to load random items in my Ember application. To do this, I do the following:

```
Test.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        randomItem: function() {
            var route = this;
            $.getJSON('item/random.json', function(data) {
                Test.Item.find(data).then(function(item) {
                    route.transitionTo('items.show', item);
                });
        });
    }, // ..... etc
```

This works fine, except for one thing: nested-sideloaded data is not shown. When `items.show` is visited via a `{{#linkTo 'items.show' item}}`, the item's child data is also loaded and visible. However, when this `randomItem` event is fired, only the direct children are shown. The children of the children are not.

Why is this and/or how do I fix this?

Comment: I've edited to reflect the following: the FIRST time this code is called, data is loaded and shown as expected/desired. Any SUBSEQUENT time, Ember-data does sideload the artifacts - my Rails server shows the ajax request with the proper response. So it seems just to be Ember not updating the view correctly when the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the reason the artifacts are not being shown is that I try to listen to `controller.content.isLoaded` to adapt the view to show a loading image if the content is still loading.

For some reason, the following shows the `loading...` text and icon forever on subsequent usages of the route:

```
{{#if controller.model.isLoaded}}
    <div class="row">
        </div>
        {{#each artifact in controller}}
            {{render "artifacts.show" artifact}}
        {{else}}
            <span class="muted">There are no artifacts.</span>
        {{/each}}
{{else}}
    <i class="icon-spin icon-spinner icon-large"></i> Loading...
{{/if}}
```

If anyone knows why, please let me know, so I can solve this problem.